# $state.go not redirecting but its loading the content with 200 OK

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router

Here is the plunker link for the code http://plnkr.co/edit/JwM8t3oNepP3tE1nUXlM?p=info

controller.js

```
if(($scope.login==='Admin')&&($scope.password==='admin'))
{
    $state.go('login.home');
}
```

script.js

```
var DailyUsageApp = angular.module('DailyUsageApp', ['ui.router']);
DailyUsageApp.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
  $stateProvider.state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: "login.html",
      controller: 'authController'
    })
    .state('login.home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller: 'homeController'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is because you are creating hierarchical states, that are not meant to be hierarchical. By naming your state `login.home`, you are saying that `home` is a child of `login`. This means that when you try and `go('login.home')` ui router is attempting to render the login state as well as the home state as a child. This means that for your current layout to work, the login template must contain its own `ui-view` tag. The best way to fix this is to simply rename your state to just `home`, and then use `$state.go('home');`

Answer (score 1):

There is [an updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KGuefajjpu3VVWpbOZ5x?p=preview)

The most simple solution is to **NOT** make state `login.home` nested under `login`.

```
//.state('login.home', {
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: "home.html",
  controller: 'homeController'
});
```

There are also other solutions, like create a target for `login.home` inside of the `login` like this:

```
<div ui-view=""></div
```

But usually, we do not do that. Just login and then navigate to some other state hierarchy...